# How to parse HTTP headers using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I need to get 2 values from a web page header that I am getting using curl.  I have been able to get the values individually using:

```
response1=$(curl -I -s http://www.example.com | grep HTTP/1.1 | awk {'print $2'})
response2=$(curl -I -s http://www.example.com | grep Server: | awk {'print $2'})
```

But I cannot figure out how to grep the values separately using a single curl request like:

```
response=$(curl -I -s http://www.example.com)
http_status=$response | grep HTTP/1.1 | awk {'print $2'}
server=$response | grep Server: | awk {'print $2'}
```

Every attempt either leads to a error message or empty values.  I am sure it is just a syntax issue.

Comment: doing `$response |...` won't work because the value of `$response` is not a command. `echo $response` should work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Full `bash`solution. Demonstrate how to easily parse other headers without requiring `awk`:

```
shopt -s extglob # Required to trim whitespace; see below

while IFS=':' read key value; do
    # trim whitespace in "value"
    value=${value##+([[:space:]])}; value=${value%%+([[:space:]])}

    case "$key" in
        Server) SERVER="$value"
                ;;
        Content-Type) CT="$value"
                ;;
        HTTP*) read PROTO STATUS MSG <<< "$key{$value:+:$value}"
                ;;
     esac
done < <(curl -sI http://www.google.com)
echo $STATUS
echo $SERVER
echo $CT
```

Producing:

```
302
GFE/2.0
text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

---

According to [RFC-2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), HTTP headers are modeled as described in [*"Standard for the Format of ARPA Internet Text Messages"* (RFC822)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt), which states clearly section 3.1.2:

> The  field-name must be composed of printable ASCII characters
> (i.e., characters that  have  values  between  33.  and  126.,
> decimal, except colon).  The field-body may be composed of any
> ASCII characters, except CR or LF.  (While CR and/or LF may be
> present  in the actual text, they are removed by the action of
> unfolding the field.)

So the above script *should* catch any RFC-[2]822 compliant header *with the notable exception of [folded headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.2.3)*.

Comment: Why is the HTTP* case different than the others?  I am a bash n00b, so please forgive me if the question is really basic.

Comment: @JPShook `IFS=':'` means I break input as key/value based on the `:` character. The HTTP status line does not have that format. So it is a _special case_.

Comment: I think the `HTTP*` case could be better written as `read PROTO STATUS MSG <<<"$key$value"` in case the message contains a colon (and making use of `<<<`, which is conceptually simpler than spawning a child to echo.)

Comment: @rici Thank you for your comment. Very good catch! I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried this method. I am also reading a header that returns "online" and when i echo it is shows as online, but when I try to do a comparison to "online" it does not match.  Any ideas?  Do they need to be trimmed or something?

Comment: @JPShook Remember that in the case statement you place the "field-name". For RFC-822/RCF-2822 compliant headers, space is not allowed as a field name character. You don't have to trim anything (I've add a bit of background info in my answer). May I suggest you capture the full header to a file in order to examine how it is structured -- and _if_ you are not able to fix the script to deal with that particular header, to ask _an other question_ with the relevant pieces of data.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I have not included any spaces in the field name.  The value that is coming back has some hidden characters, newlines or something causing it to not only be comprised of the value I am looking for.  Any way to trim/remove newline chars from the value?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Ended up using a wildcard in the condition.  Would it be possible for you to update your answer to strip the results of each header value of any extra spaces, newlines, etc?

Comment: @JPShook I've updated my answer to trim whitespace in the value field. You now have all the basic building blocks to adapt to your special need. BTW the issue you had while parsing your very specific header is weird. You definitively should post that (incl. the header raw data of course) as new question. That would be an interesting puzzle game to solve...

Comment: The whitespace trim fixed the issue so I no longer have to use the wildcard match.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to extract more than a couple of headers, you could stuff all the headers into a bash associative array. Here's a simple-minded function which assumes that any given header only occurs once. (Don't use it for `Set-Cookie`; see below.)

```
# Call this as: headers ARRAY URL
headers () {
  {
    # (Re)define the specified variable as an associative array.
    unset $1;
    declare -gA $1;
    local line rest

    # Get the first line, assuming HTTP/1.0 or above. Note that these fields
    # have Capitalized names.
    IFS=$' \t\n\r' read $1[Proto] $1[Status] rest
    # Drop the CR from the message, if there was one.
    declare -gA $1[Message]="${rest%$'\r'}"
    # Now read the rest of the headers. 
    while true; do
      # Get rid of the trailing CR if there is one.
      IFS=$'\r' read line rest;
      # Stop when we hit an empty line
      if [[ -z $line ]]; then break; fi
      # Make sure it looks like a header
      # This regex also strips leading and trailing spaces from the value
      if [[ $line =~ ^([[:alnum:]_-]+):\ *(( *[^ ]+)*)\ *$ ]]; then
        # Force the header to lower case, since headers are case-insensitive,
        # and store it into the array
        declare -gA $1[${BASH_REMATCH[1],,}]="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
      else
        printf "Ignoring non-header line: %q\n" "$line" >> /dev/stderr
      fi
    done
  } < <(curl -Is "$2")
}
```

Example:

```
$ headers so http://stackoverflow.com/
$ for h in ${!so[@]}; do printf "%s=%s\n" $h "${so[$h]}"; done | sort
Message=OK
Proto=HTTP/1.1
Status=200
cache-control=public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", max-age=43
content-length=224904
content-type=text/html; charset=utf-8
date=Fri, 25 Jul 2014 17:35:16 GMT
expires=Fri, 25 Jul 2014 17:36:00 GMT
last-modified=Fri, 25 Jul 2014 17:35:00 GMT
set-cookie=prov=205fd7f3-10d4-4197-b03a-252b60df7653; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
vary=*
x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN
```

Note that the SO response includes one or more cookies, in `Set-Cookie` headers, but we can only see the last one because the naive script overwrites entries with the same header name. (As it happens, there was only one but we can't know that.) While it would be possible to augment the script to special case `Set-Cookie`, a better approach would probably be to provide a cookie-jar file, and use the `-b` and `-c` curl options in order to maintain it.

Comment: How do you add a timeout to your solution?

Comment: @djuarez: I'd probably use the `timeout` command to wrap the entire script, but bash's `read` builtin has an option for setting a timeout if it were acceptable to do the timeout per line.

Answer (score 2):

Using process substitution, (`<( ... )`) you are able to read into shell variable:

```
sh$ read STATUS SERVER < <(
      curl -sI http://www.google.com | 
      awk '/^HTTP/ { STATUS = $2 } 
           /^Server:/ { SERVER = $2 } 
           END { printf("%s %s\n",STATUS, SERVER) }'
    )

sh$ echo $STATUS
302
sh$ $ echo $SERVER
GFE/2.0
```

Comment: What if there were 20 properties to be read, would you suggest the same approach?

Comment: @JPShook As of myself, I would either use `awk` or `bash`. In most of the cases, it doesn't add much here to use _both of them_. But without enough background, I have only speculated that you wanted an hybrid solution.

Comment: @JPShook I posted an other answer demonstrating how you could use `bash` alone. Depending your needs, this might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Improved and modernized [@rici's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24961572/7939871) with Bash >=4.2 features:

- Use `declare -n` nameref variable to reference the associative array.
- Use `declare -l` automatically lowercased variable value.
- Use `${var@a}` to query variable declaration attributes.
- Change to process the input stream rather than call the `curl` command.
- Make it compatible with [RFC-2822's Folded Headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.2.3)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob # Requires extended globbing

# Process the input headers stream into an associative ARRAY
# @Arguments
# $1: The associative array receiving headers
# @Input
# &1: The headers stream
parse_headers() {
  if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    printf 'Need an associative array name argument\n' >&2
    return 1
  fi
  local -n header=$1 # Nameref argument
  # Check that argument is the name of an associative array
  case ${header@a} in
    A | At) ;;
    *)
      printf \
      'Variable %s with attributes %s is not a suitable associative array\n' \
      "${!header}" "${header@a}" >&2
      return 1
      ;;
  esac
  header=() # Clear the associative array
  local -- line rest v
  local -l k # Automatically lowercased

  # Get the first line, assuming HTTP/1.0 or above. Note that these fields
  # have Capitalized names.
  IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r header['Proto'] header['Status'] rest
  # Drop the CR from the message, if there was one.
  header['Message']="${rest%%*([[:space:]])}"
  # Now read the rest of the headers.
  while IFS=$'\r\n: ' read -d $'\r' -r line rest && [ -n "$line$rest" ]; do
    rest=${rest%%*([[:space:]])}
    rest=${rest##*([[:space:]])}
    line=${line%%*([[:space:]])}
    [ -z "$line" ] && break # Blank line is end of headers stream
    if [ -n "$rest" ]; then
      k=$line
      v=$rest
    else
      # Handle folded header
      # See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.2.3
      v+=" ${line##*([[:space:]])}"
    fi
    header["$k"]="$v"
  done
}

declare -A HTTP_HEADERS

parse_headers HTTP_HEADERS < <(
  curl \
    --silent \
    --head \
    --location \
    https://stackoverflow.com/q/24943170/7939871
)

for k in "${!HTTP_HEADERS[@]}"; do
  printf '[%q]=%q\n' "$k" "${HTTP_HEADERS[$k]}"
done

typeset -p HTTP_HEADERS
```