# How to parse HTTP headers by /bin/sh?

Tags: linux, bash, sh, embedded-linux

Here - [How to parse HTTP headers using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943170/how-to-parse-http-headers-using-bash) there is very elegant solution to parse in bash without awk:

```
shopt -s extglob # Required to trim whitespace; see below

while IFS=':' read key value; do
    # trim whitespace in "value"
    value=${value##+([[:space:]])}; value=${value%%+([[:space:]])}

    case "$key" in
       Server) SERVER="$value"
               ;;
       Content-Type) CT="$value"
               ;;
       HTTP*) read PROTO STATUS MSG <<< "$key{$value:+:$value}"
               ;;
    esac
done < <(curl -sI http://www.google.com)
echo $STATUS
echo $SERVER
echo $CT
```

but how to transform it for pure sh ?

I also intend to use wget rather than curl, but seems I can handle that.

Comment: It would be better to include everything required into this question right here - as it is, you expect people to go elsewhere first.

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: firstly it turnrd that sh does not have "here string" and therefore <<< doesnot work, secondly redirection in "done < <(curl... " raises syntax error: unexpected redirection and for now these seems to be major stopers

Comment: `checkbashisms` reports: `possible bashism in curlparse.bash line 1 (shopt):
shopt -s extglob # Required to trim whitespace; see below
possible bashism in curlparse.bash line 12 (<<< here string):
       HTTP*) read PROTO STATUS MSG <<< "$key{$value:+:$value}"
possible bashism in curlparse.bash line 15 (<() process substituion):
done < <(curl -sI http://www.google.com)
`. That's a reasonable starting point for fixing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trim whitespace by using `read` with a here document. Use a named pipe to "simulate" the process substitution. (Process substitution may in fact be implemented with named pipes on some operating systems.)

```
mkfifo headers
curl -sI http://www.google.com > headers &

{
  # This line is guaranteed to be first, before any headers.
  # Read it separately.
  read -r PROTO STATUS MSG
  while IFS=':' read -r key value; do
      # trim whitespace in "value"
      read -r value <<EOF
$value
EOF

      case $key in
         Server) SERVER="$value"
                 ;;
         Content-Type) CT="$value"
                 ;;
      esac
  done
} < headers
rm headers
```

I leave it as an exercise to research how to indent the body of the here document properly.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the actual system has busybox and does have some external comands like rm but not mkfifo.  But why direct piping to {} does not work?

Comment: If you don't have `mkfifo`, there's little point in sticking with `/bin/sh`; you aren't targeting a POSIX-compliant system.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `extglob`, you can trim whitespace with

```
set -- $value
value=$*
```

This will alse squash field-internal whitespace, but that seems harmless in this context. It will also perform wildcard expansion, which is a more pesky problem; `set -f` would fix that, if you can use it.

However, perhaps the simplest solution is to pipe to a simple Awk script which assigns the variables, so you can `eval` them.

```
eval $(curl -sI http://www.google.com |
    awk -v q="'" '{ gsub(/\r/, ""); gsub(q, q "\"" q "\"" q); }
        /HTTP\// { print "PROTO=" q $1 q; 
            print "STATUS=" q $2 q; print "MSG=" q $3 q; next }
        /^Server: / { $1="SERVER=" q; $NF = $NF q; sub(q " ", q); print; next; }
        /^Content-Type: / { $1="CT=" q; $NF = $NF q; sub(q " ", q); print; next; }')
```

The single quotes should hopefully be enough to assure that the `eval` is safe, though I'm sure the whitespace handling could be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

This is tested with [heirloom-sh](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html). It should work with any bourne shell you find:

```
(curl -I -s http://www.example.com;echo)| (
read HTTP_VAR_PROTO HTTP_VAR_STATUS HTTP_VAR_MSG
while IFS=': ' read -r key value; do
    case "$key" in
       Server) HTTP_VAR_SERVER="$value"
               ;;
       Content-Type) HTTP_VAR_CONTENT_TYPE="$value"
               ;;
       '')
        set #remove "set" and put your script here
        ;;
    esac
done
)
```

I've prefixed the set vars with `HTTP_VAR_` to avoid letting the HTTP response overwrite important bits of the environment. It stinks that you have to put your script *inside* the `case`, but there's no way (without using external programs or `eval`ing input) to get `read` to work the way you want in bog-standard bourne.

Comment: You can use a named pipe instead of the anonymous pipe to avoid running the `while` loop in a subshell.

Comment: Yes you can use a named pipe. I tend to avoid doing so because of the difficulty of getting a safe name, particularly under the restriction of staying within `sh`. If `mktemp -d` is available, that's one safer way to do it, but you still have race conditions around deletion. If there's a safer way to get a named pipe created and deleted, in a shell that doesn't also have process substitution, I'd be very interested in learning about it.

Comment: True, but if you have that level of concern, you are probably better off not using shell at all, and using a language with a proper library for handling HTTP.

Comment: The question asked to stay in pure `sh`. If external commands (e.g. `mknod`, `rm`) are allowed, then this gets much simpler.